# Handle camera orientation in zxing QR code

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, zxing

I am developing an application which reads QR codes. So I used *zxing* library for reading QR codes. I successfully read a QR code in my application.

The problem is that when I start my application in landscape mode, the zxing camera works fine, but when I rotate my device to portrait mode, the camera remains in landscape mode – ie tilted 90 degrees.

I use the Android project from zxing 2.1 as a library project in my app.

What should I do in order to be able to use the application in both orientations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont change in library. And dont use intent code. Just call library. Then it works fine.

Comment: If you mean that you can use the core scanning library regardless of orientation, yes. You do need to write your own app to use portrait mode, but that's something that should be done anyway.